Swift Warning on requesting location access
In my map view model (shown below), everything is working fine, it's just a purple warning that keeps coming up that says:
This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the -locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking authorizationStatus` first.
on the: "if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()" line
import Foundation
import MapKit

final class MapViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.773972, longitude: -122.431297), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    
    @Published var accurateUserLocationRetrieved: Bool = false
    
    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager!.delegate = self
        } else {
            print("Show alert letting them know it is off and tell them to turn on.")
        }
    }
    
    private func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else { return }
        
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
            
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Your location is restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("Your have denied location permission")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
            self.accurateUserLocationRetrieved = true
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
}

I tried checking for for locationServicesEnabled in the class init() but this led to the same warning.

Thanks for your responses Matt. I have tried setting the class to @MainActor and this leads to the same error. If it is of any help, i am calling the function in the view like this
.onChange(of: locationEnabled) { oldValue, newValue in
if locationEnabled {
mapViewModel.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()
}
}
Thanks for your help!

Sorry, I got the whole thing backwards. See my answer below.

The trick here is that you need to either do what the warning suggests or else get the call to locationServicesEnabled() off the main thread. But if you choose the latter approach, the rest of your method needs to be on the main thread.

One approach is to define a global actor on which you can call locationServicesEnabled:
@globalActor actor MyGlobalActor: GlobalActor {
    private static var instance = MyGlobalActor()
    static var shared: MyGlobalActor { instance }
}

Now you can wrap the calls in Tasks:
@MyGlobalActor func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        Task { @MainActor in
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager?.delegate = self
        }
    } else {
        print("Show alert...")
    }
}

func callCheckIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
    Task {
        await checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()
    }
}

If you call callCheck..., the call to locationServicesEnabled() will not raise the warning.

A somewhat more lightweight approach, without the global actor, might look like this, using a detached Task to get on a background context:
func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
    Task.detached { [self] in
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            Task { @MainActor in
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                locationManager?.delegate = self
            }
        } else {
            print("Show alert...")
        }
    }
}


However, I think it would be better to do what the warning suggests, if at all possible.
